# Concentric Circles & Section/Breakout Confusion

Tags: cad, technical-drawing, drafting, drawings

This is part of my on going saga of drafting question with respect to the [V2 drawings](http://www.digipeer.de/index.php?static=52) I am using for practice while learning inventor.

The following [drawing](http://www.digipeer.de/index.php?media=DMA_FA_014_01379&size=2) is titled "Partition" (Zwischenwand in German).  The lower front view has a break away section that leaves me confused.

[image]

Part of the problem may stem from the annotation at the top of the drawing that has been marred by a black streak that blacks out the end of the note Bo 35 DIN L4_____ as well as the dimensions for the small hole pair spacing at the top which I have assumed to be 35 which has worked out well.  According to google translate Bo is either gust or squall.  When I translated Press, punch, blow, and push into google translate I did not get Bo in German.  Not being a literate in German this could just be a limitation of Google translate.

Based on the 35 dimension elsewhere I confirmed the outer concentric circle is 35 mm diameter.  I guessed that the interior circle is 27.

**What are the concentric circles and how is it related to the cut away in the front view?**

I originally thought the interior circle was a hole and the outer was a beveled edge.  However, I thought that was a pretty big bevel for 1 mm thick plate.

My second thought was they could have been "dimples" added to give the plate some rigidity.  This would  mean that the interior circle would be flat parallel plane to the main sheet and the space between the two circles would be the stretched material that would be slanted forming a cut off cone.  This is the only thing I could think of based on the cut out.  I am guessing the "Dimple" would be 3 mm deep based on scaling of front view.

Comment: Sadly, my german was not that usefull as well. However, I might note that another part that belongs to the same assembly as this one has the exact same concentric circle thingy. In here they were clearly labeled Bö 35 DIN L401. Furthermore, that drawing is a tad clearer and shows they are indeed dimples. I am assuming this Bö thingy is the name of the press or stamp that is used to create these dimples. Finding that however...

Comment: FYI: http://www.digipeer.de/index.php?media=DMA_FA_014_15531&size=2

Comment: I found the label clear on another drawing but it was very similar to the this one.  The one you linked is much clearer.  I apparently have not worked my way down to that sheet yet. 8)  Good job and nice find.

Comment: @Petrus1904 The thing that is slightly confusing between the part you found and the drawing in this question, is that its 2 concentric circles in the question and 3 for the part you found.  I will chalk it up to scale!