# Revolving section around axis in Inventor

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I am following up with this [other question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48056/concentric-circles-section-breakout-confusion).  I am using Inventor LT 2021. (can only make parts, no assemblies)

I started drawing up the concentric circles as if they were dimples.  I figured it would be good practice.  In order to do this, after extruding the main plate with the circles excluded I then extruded the central circle 3 then repeated the extrusion and subtracted 2.

[image]

I then made 4 working planes perpendicular to the sheet and passing through the centers of the dimples.

[image]

On these planes at each circle I drew a cross section connecting the upper plate to the lower plate on one side.  I did this with the intent of revolving the section around the axis of the circle in order to fill in the space between the lower plate (small circle) and the main plate (large circle).

[image]

Once complete for all circles, I proceeded to use the axis function to create an axis through center of circular or elliptical edge.

[image]

[image]

When I went to use the revolve function, I could select the section to be revolved but not the axis to revolve around. I attempted this at a couple of different locations in case I missed a snap when I drew the sections.  While gathering all the screen shots for this I tried selecting the axis first and low and behold it worked where before it did not.

[image]

**Why was I not able to chose the section first and then choose the axis that I had created  second?**

**Is there a better process for creating all the dimples?**

The process seemed rather labour intensive doing each one individually as opposed to doing one then copying it.  In Autocad I would have created one dimple and copied it to the required location as needed and then unioned the dimples with the main part when I was done.

Comment: Asssuming this is a sheetmetal part, the punch tool is probably the thing you need. It is a fairly complicated toolbox to grasp, however, this will allow you to draw punches or stamps correctly. That is, with the correct bendings, and not a perfect slope.

Comment: @Petrus1904 I'll go hunting for this punch tool you speak of.  I would call this sheet metal but I tend to work with steel plate.  In this drawing, the material is 1 mm thick.

Comment: @Petrus1904 After completing a google search, it turns out that Inventor LT does not have the sheet metal functionality.

Comment: Extrude boss with draft, and then extrude cut to make it hollow - but however you do it, make it once and use the pattern tool.